# How to update GitHub authentification token on Rstudio to match the new policy?

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio, access-token

While pushing a commit to GitHub yesterday, I received an email from the GitHub team:

> Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.
>
> Thanks,
> The GitHub Team

I don't understand a word of the help page...
I did create a more secure access token a few months ago when they first announced the change in authentification, and entered it in the terminal of my mac. I thought that would be it. My question is: **how to update an Rstudio session created when token weren't necessary to match the new access-token policy?**

Thanks in advance for your help,
Rosalie

Comment: Perhaps https://happygitwithr.com/credential-caching.html#credential-caching can help

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I don't know how to validate user @r2evans' comment above, but indeed it worked!
I already had a PAT token set, so I followed the steps in https://happygitwithr.com/credential-caching.html#credential-caching, starting at 10.2.1.1

```
install.packages("gitcreds")
library(gitcreds)
gitcreds_set()
```

I had to enter my account password (computer password), then it showed my current identification parameters.
In the console, three choices appear:

```
1: Keep these credentials
2: Replace these credentials
3: See the password / token
```

Select 2 to replace the password/token (credentials), and voilà!

Thanks for the easy fix @r2evans.

Comment: This worked! It was enough to run gitcreds_set() and insert token, and problem was solved. It should be noted that when prompted for password/token you must add a token. You may have to make the token first. To make a token, see ths recipe: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: And (note to future self), the token should not be in quotes!

Answer (score 11):

@r2evans this was very helpful!

For future visitors of this thread, running `gitcreds_set()` will prompt a dialog in Rstudio that will ask you what you would like to do with your previous existing user/password credentials.

```
1: Keep these credentials
2: Replace these credentials
3: See the password / token
```

By opting for 2, I replaced my credentials with an existing [token that I already created](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) on Github. It worked seamlessly!

Comment: The options didn't come for me, but I just entered the PAT when I was asked for user and pass (when I pushed from RStudio)

Answer (score 7):

The solutions above didn't work for me. I had to use:

```r
credentials::set_github_pat("my_pat")
```

Then when prompted by the pop-up boxes I had to use my PAT as my password.

Comment: That is also what I had to do. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: not wrong, but why did they make this step so tedious? Pop-up boxes not ok for me.