# RStudio/Git trouble pushing

Tags: github, rstudio, push

Hello I am running  RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775ebddc40635780ca1ed238934c3345c5de, 2022-07-22) for macOS and I can not push to GitHUb.

I have tried to change from HTTPS to SSH but nothing worked so far, I have all the identifications but I do not how to solve it, please could you please help me. I am lost

[image]

I want to push projects to GitHub, I have tried many times change from HTTPS to SSH and a new key , also I have verify the connection to ssh and everything seems to work.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to stick with HTTPS URL, [and use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71031164/6309):

```
credentials::set_github_pat("my_pat")
```

(Use your [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))

That should be enough to allow you to push from RStudio.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but "my _pat", which path should be there?

Comment: Not path, pat: your GitHub personal access token